# How to change background image

Tags: javascript, if-statement, background-image

I am a beginner in JS and am trying to create a simple function where I click on a button and the background image changes but it doesn't work (I was trying to recreate a simpler image slider). I can't understand why.

This is my JS. I have used the absolute link hoping it could fix the problem and the alert to see whether the if/else statement was working.

```
const btnLeft = document.getElementById("btn-left");
const btnRight = document.getElementById("btn-right");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked() {
if (btnLeft.clicked) {
document.getElementById("img2").style.backgroundImage = 
"url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494783367193-149034c05e8f?ixlib=rb- 
1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=diego-jimenez-A-NVHPka9Rk-unsplash.jpg')";
} else alert("no click!");

}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="slide-container">

    <div class="slide" id="img1">
       <button id="btn-left"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x " ></i></button>
        <button id="btn-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x " ></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="img2">

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the relevant CSS.

```
 .slide-container {
display: flex;  
 }

.slide:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url(../img/img1.jpg);
height: 789px;
width: 100%; 
flex-shrink: 0;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url(../img/img2.jpg);
height: 789px;
width: 100%; 
flex-shrink: 0;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#btn-left {
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
}
#btn-right {
position: absolute;
left: 1380px;
top: 400px;
}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated, I have been going crazy for hours! Thanks.

EDIT. After David784's help, I now have this:

```
const btnLeft = document.getElementById("btn-left");
const btnRight = document.getElementById("btn-right");


btnLeft.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked(e) {
if (e.currentTarget === btnLeft ) {
document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = 
"url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494783367193-149034c05e8f? 
ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=diego-jimenez- 
A-NVHPka9Rk-unsplash.jpg')";
} 
else alert("no click!");
}
```

and it works. But then when I try to add the same for the right button, such as

```
function whenClicked(e) {
if (e.currentTarget === btnRight ) {
document.getElementById("img1").style.backgroundImage = 
"url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494783367193-149034c05e8f? 
ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=diego- 
jimenez-A-NVHPka9Rk-unsplash.jpg')";
} 
else alert("no click!");
}
```

the left button stopped working. Why?

Comment: Does your Function fire when the buttons are clicked? Have you tried adding an alert(...) / Console.Log(...) etc to see if it does?

Comment: the else bit in the if-else statement was exactly to see whether it was working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question makes it sound as if the `backgroundImage` part is where the problem is, but I can't seem to duplicate (see working snippet below).

However I did have trouble with the `if (btnLeft.clicked)`...I'm not sure `Element.clicked` is a thing...at least I've never seen it before. When I changed it to `e.currentTarget===btnLeft`, it just worked. (See  [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) for more info).

```js
const btnLeft = document.getElementById("btn-left");
const btnRight = document.getElementById("btn-right");

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);
btnRight.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget === btnLeft) {
    document.getElementById("img2").style.backgroundImage =
      "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494783367193-149034c05e8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=diego-jimenez-A-NVHPka9Rk-unsplash.jpg')";
  } else alert("no click!");

}
```

```css
.slide-container {
  display: flex;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(../img/img1.jpg);
  height: 789px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(../img/img2.jpg);
  height: 789px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#btn-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

#btn-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1380px;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">

  <div class="slide" id="img1">
    <button id="btn-left"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x " >left</i></button>
    <button id="btn-right"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x " >right</i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="slide" id="img2">

  </div>

</div>
```

*Edit: to address the comment about CSS, this is addressed by [CSS Specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Which states:

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight: bold;") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

When doing `element.style.backgroundImage`, this creates an inline style, which will override. (with the exception I think of `!important` rules, which you should almost never use anyway)

To address the question about passing the event into the event handler: this is a very helpful tool when using events, called the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

> e.target is incredibly useful when you want to set the same event handler on multiple elements and do something to all of them when an event occurs on them.

So the event object can be named pretty much whatever you want. You could call it `e`, `event`, `evnt`, or whatever. But it will give you access to a lot of very useful information, like the `target` of the click, the x/y coordinates of the click, etc.

Or in this case [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), which is slightly different than `target`, gives us access to the element that the event handler is actually attached to. (here the `target` would most likely be the `i` tag inside the `button` tag).

Comment: Thank you!! It's working now! Is it possible that it's not working for you because you don't have the link for the current background? In other words, I only provide the link of what I want the background to change in, nothing says what my current background is. 

Regarding the eventTarget, what I dont understand is why pass the "event" as parameter of the function? Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @GraceWanders I added some additional notes at the bottom of my answer to address your questions. Hope this helps! If it's useful and/or answers your question, perhaps you might consider upvoting and marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I get this message when trying to upvote: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. 

So now my last question is... if i wanted to turn this into a proper image carousel, I would definitely need arrays, right?